# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

when I try to install Microsoft Server Management Studio I get stuck on "Loading packages, Please wait ...", I tried to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server but nothing works ...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried waiting?

Comment: Also uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Server will have no effect. SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio are completely separate applications.

Comment: Yeah i tried, nothing work :(...